# Looking for a 3D computer model of a raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

I can generate my own model in Autocad 2013, or Autocad Inventor, but why re-invent pi? Can anyone point me at a 3D model I can download?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a google sketchup model here:

```
http://engineerdemos.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/raspberry-pi-3d-model-and-google.html
```

If you need the model in AutoCAD, i would suggest exporting if, although you need the pro version of sketchup.

see here:

```
http://help.sketchup.com/en/article/36203
```

EDIT:

You can find an AutoCAD model here (but in my opinion, you might be better off with the sketchup model)

```
http://goo.gl/yTHNl9
```

Comment: I was able to use a demo version of Sketchup to export to Autocad 3D. Thanks.